# ¿Por qué la consulta SQL trae el usuario y clave sin importar si está en mayúscula o minúscula?

Tags: mysql, sql

Intento hacer  un **SELECT** para traer el usuario y contraseña, esos datos están en minúscula pero si yo  hago la consulta  con letras mayúsculas igual la trae, esto no  debe ocurrir. ¿A que se debe? es un  error en la base de datos o en la consulta?

```
SELECT empleado.empl_nom, empleado.empl_ape, empleado.empl_doc, acceso.acce_perfil ,acceso.acce_usuario ,acceso.acce_clave 
         FROM empleado,acceso 
           WHERE acceso.empl_doc=empleado.empl_doc 
             AND   acceso.acce_usuario='NUTRICIONISTA' 
             AND  acceso.acce_clave='NUTRICIONISTA'
             AND acceso.acce_estado='activo'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Gracias, funciono con perefectamente con BINARY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En este caso vemos que hace falta el atributo `BINARY` para que puedas realizar la consulta de manera exitosa.

```
SELECT empleado.empl_nom, empleado.empl_ape, empleado.empl_doc, acceso.acce_perfil ,acceso.acce_usuario ,acceso.acce_clave 
         FROM empleado,acceso 
           WHERE acceso.empl_doc=empleado.empl_doc 
             AND   acceso.acce_usuario= BINARY 'NUTRICIONISTA' 
             AND  acceso.acce_clave= BINARY 'NUTRICIONISTA'
             AND acceso.acce_estado= BINARY'activo'
```

Prueba con este `sql` y ya no debería traer la consulta.

Espero haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: Si funciona de esa manera,gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que haya sido de ayuda, para encontrar más información acerca de los tipos de datos SQL te invito a que leas esto: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/2336.php